# Обработка нажатия по пункту контекстного меню - WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi

Создал приложение, свернул в панель задач. Создал контекстное меню из одного пункта, оно успешно вызывается по ПКМ. Теперь, хотелось бы обработать нажатие по пункту меню. Вот код, но он не срабатывает:

```
case TREY_MESSAGE: //  своя константа
{
    switch (lParam)
    {
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    {
        // Извлекаю координаты курсора мыши
        GetCursorPos(&pt); // т.к. координаты не передаются в функцию, берём напрямую
        // Отображаем меню
        TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);

        return 0;
    }
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        // щёлчек левой кнопкой мышки

        return 0;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        // отладчик здесь не останавливается
        MessageBoxA(hwnd, "test", "test", MB_OK);
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == MENU_EXIT) // MENU_EXIT - идентификатор пункта меню
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, lParam, wParam);
        return 0;
    }
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Блоки WM_RBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONUP(этот для теста) обрабатываются, а вот в WM_COMMAND упорно не заходит. Как лечить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Вы ищете сообщение `WM_COMMAND` не там, куда операционная система может его отправить. `WM_COMMAND` — это полноценное сообщение, код которого хранится в параметре `Msg`. Вы же пытаетесь работать с ним как с кодом, пересылаемым в рамках `TREY_MESSAGE`, ища его в `lParam` (подобно кодам уведомлений в `WM_NOTIFY`).
2. `WM_COMMAND` проверяется внутри `case`-ветки, работающей с `TREY_MESSAGE`, хотя это равноправные сообщения.